# Split each row in a column whose value contains commas into transposed rows

Tags: google-sheets

So I have data in the following format:

[image: Data]

I want to summarize this into another sheet like this:

[image: Output]

So I can use `TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1:A))` to do this individually

I can use `ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A:A))` to run this over a range, however I cant seem to use both of them together to the same effect

To summarize

Column A contains comma seperated values for car names

I want to get all the car names as rows in another sheet and add counts against them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the whole mini-report with this one formula:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A,","))),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) Where Col1 > '@' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''"))`

`SPLIT` will split every entry in A2:A at the comma (if there is one) and will result in an error for every blank row (dealt with later).

`TRIM` removes the spaces after any comma-splits.

`FLATTEN` creates one column from all results (words, blanks and errors).

`QUERY(...,"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) Where Col1 > '@' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''")` starts with everything in that `FLATTEN` column and a `COUNT` of each `GROUP`ed by the name ruling out anything `WHERE` the value in Col1 is not > the '@' symbol (which will rule out all blanks and errors). Finally, `LABEL` will get rid of the superfluous header of "count" that would otherwise be generated for the `COUNT(Col1)` column of the `QUERY`.

Alternatively, you could rule out the errors *first* with a `FILTER` and then use the `WHERE` part of the `QUERY` to rule out blanks:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),","))),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''"))`

Comment: this is perfect.

Comment: On that how do I select the list of people instead of count
Chevrolet: Ayuna, Amelia ;;; Toyota: Amelia, John

Comment: In keeping with the purpose of this forum (i.e., streamlining a method for future visitors to easily find answers to similar issues), please ask separate questions by submitting a new post. You may link to this post from the new post, but explain the new issue you are trying to solve clearly in the new post, as if this post did not exist. I'll try to keep an eye out.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it from this question
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114791/google-sheets-split-and-unique

```
=unique(transpose(arrayformula(trim(split(join(",",A1:A),",")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient is probably `QUERY`. Unlike `JOIN`, this has no limit on the number of characters in the result.

#### Basic approach

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
  QUERY(A:A&",",,9^9),
  ", "
)))
```

[image]

#### Unique

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
  QUERY(A:A&",",,9^9),
  ", "
))))
```

[image]

#### Counting the number in a group

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(A:A&",",,9^9),", ")),
  "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"
))
```

[image]